# Android: Is it correct to poll an api in the repository layer?

Tags: android, rest, mvvm, repository, viewmodel

I will be injecting this repository class into each of my viewModels that require it. The following is the init block for the repository.

```
init {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            while(true) {
                when (val response = getData()) {
                    is ApiResponse.Success -> {
                        response.data?.let {
                            data = it
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {}
                }
                delay(5000)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The repository layer should be the holders to make any api call/db operations you should just suspend those functions, I follow MVVM pattern.

While in your viewModel you should fetch the data using coroutines with the help of viewModelscope.launch{ } while inside a viewModel and lifecylceScope.launch{ } if you're making a call from fragment or activity.

Avoid using GlobalScope as it stick with the application class lifecyle, hence not an optimal scope.

I hope I made your doubt clear.

Answer (score 1):

as #Sourabh Bhatt mentioned, you should define api calls inside your repository class as suspend functions and then, inside your viewModel class call that methods by using viewModelScope , that is special coroutine scope to use inside viewModel and that scope is destroyed automatically when viewModel is destroyed.

Comment: I need the API to be polled throughout the app's lifecycle and data available for every screen. If I include this code in viewModelScope, it would stop calling when the ViewModel clears

Comment: while you are calling api inside your viewModel , then response of that api is used inside that view model and if viewModel is cleared, response of that api is not needed in that viewModel if viewModel is gone, you better bound lifetime of api call to view lifecycle , if you need to wait for response of api call untill application is alive , then you call it from mainActivity with lifecylceScope, and consume response in any fragment , globalScope is rarely used and using async or launch on the instance of globalScope is highly discouraged,

Comment: Wouldn't calling the api from the Activity break MVVM architecture, since the view is only supposed to access the data through the ViewModel?